# How to insert the result of a n1ql to a bucket using python SDK couchbase

Tags: python, couchbase, bucket

I want to insert the result of a n1ql into a bucket 'test' using python, and I don't know how to, I'm new to this.

I searched into the documentation python SDK using couchbase but didn't find the answer of what I'm struggling with.I don't know how to use upsert() for that..

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
from couchbase.n1ql import N1QLQuery
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost:8091')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('Administrator', 'root123')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket('test')
cb = cluster.open_bucket('pth')
cb.operationTimeout = 5000;
#N1QL Simple Query#
query = N1QLQuery("SELECT usr_id,score FROM pth ")
```

I want to have the result into the bucket 'test'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INSERT INTO SELECT statement. Example 8, 13-15 at  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/insert.html